# SQL: Nested subquery is returning entries incorrectly

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm having some trouble querying a dataset with a nested subquery, which I thought would be pretty straightforward.

I have a table of customers and their addresses `dbo.PERSON_ADDRESSES` and transactions with customers `dbo.TRANSACT_CUSTOMERS`. It is very common for customers to have multiple addresses stored in the `dbo.PERSON_ADDRESSES` table over time. I simply would like to use the most recent transaction in the `dbo.TRANSACT_CUSOMTERS` table to a table of most recent addresses from the `dbo.PERSON_ADDRESSES` table.

When I run the inner subquery independently, it works fine: it shows the one most recent transaction per customer like I envisioned. But, for some reason when I run this entire query, I obtain many, many addresses per customer. I don't understand why.

```
SELECT MaxTransaction.PERSON_ID, Addr.*
FROM dbo.PERSON_ADDRESSES AS Addr
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT PERSON_ID, Max(TRANSACTION_ID) AS MaxTID
    FROM dbo.TRANSACTION_CUSTOMERS 
    GROUP BY PERSON_ID) AS MaxTransaction
ON MaxTransaction.MaxTID = Addr.TRANSACTION_ID
```

Comment: There's no `SELECT` on your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that one transaction can have multiple customers.  To get one row per person, use an additional `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT maxp.PERSON_ID, pa.*
FROM dbo.PERSON_ADDRESSES pa JOIN
     (SELECT PERSON_ID, Max(TRANSACTION_ID) AS MaxTID
      FROM dbo.TRANSACTION_CUSTOMERS 
      GROUP BY PERSON_ID
     ) maxp
     ON maxp.person_id = pa.person_id AND
        maxp.MaxTID = pa.TRANSACTION_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. I'm a little embarrassed I didn't think of that.